# Right way to use: Vagrant vagrant_vagrantfile synced_folder to docker volumes?

Tags: windows, docker, vagrant

I'm using Windows 10, Vagrant 2.1.1 with VirtualBox 5.2.16 and trying to use Vagrant's Docker provision/provider but having allot of issues with Vagrant's synced_folder and then Docker volumes. I did get something working but want to know what the 'correct' way of doing this is:

My Vagrantfile (located at C:/projects/github.com.melissapalmer/newman-with-docker/Vagrantfile) includes at link to DockerHostVagrantfile (in a folder above VagrantFile I'm working with) eg:

```
m.vm.provider "docker" do |d|   
  ... 
  d.vagrant_vagrantfile = "C:/projects/github.com.melissapalmer/DockerHostVagrantfile"
end
```

In the C:/projects/github.com.melissapalmer/DockerHostVagrantfile file needed to include a synced_folder that was not /home/vagrant. Such as:

```
config.vm.synced_folder ".", "/home/vagrant/src"
```

And then when using the docker provider I had to map this to a volume for the Docker images eg:

```
m.vm.provider "docker" do |d|   
  ...
  d.volumes = ["/home/vagrant/src/newman-with-docker:/vagrant/newman-with-docker"]
  ... 
end
```

I found the following issues
- if I did not include a synced_folder in the DockerHostVagrantfile Vagrant creates one dynamically, I therefore don't know what to use in the Vagrantfile
- I could not use config.vm.synced_folder ".", "/home/vagrant/ in DockerHostVagrantfile  as this caused Vagrant to have SSH issues connecting to the VM 
- notice that my Vagrantfile is in a folder called newman-with-docker under root of where DockerHostVagrantfile  was.

Questions ... 
**How do you use Vagrant's synced_folder  and Docker's volumes correctly when using Vagrant vagrant_vagrantfile?**  *I've had to "hard-code" volume in Vagrantfile for Docker image eg: 
d.volumes = ["/home/vagrant/src/newman-with-docker:/vagrant/newman-with-docker"]
my code base might not always be in a folder newman-with-docker*

Comment: Windows 10 pro offers Docker for Windows - its the same as the normal Docker on linux - Worth paying a few quid for the "Win 10 pro" upgrade and get rid of Vagrant - https://www.docker.com/docker-windows

Comment: Thx, but I don’t want to use Docker For Windows ... the images I’m creating or using are backed by Linux images and therefore you need to use Docker for Unix.

Comment: 99% of images are linux images if not all but they still work on Docker for Windows - give it a play and you'll see